# functions for React Calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculator

I am working on a React Calculator. I have display with history and output and buttons for numbers and operator and was able to render it.

On my next step I want to see the number on the display when I press a number button.

I started with button number one and tried to use a useState hook and implement a handleNumbers function.
But now I can't render anything.
I wanted to do everything with functional components. Can this be fixed or should I try it with class components?

JS:

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";

//const isOperator = /[-+x/]/;

function Calculator() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("0");

  const handleNumbers = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="calculator">
        <History />
        <Output currentValue={input} />
        <Buttons />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const History = () => {
  return <div id="history"> </div>;
};

const Output = () => {
  return <div id="display">{props.currentValue}</div>;
};

const Buttons = () => {
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
      <button id="clear" value="AC" className="jumbo">
        AC
      </button>
      <button id="divide" value="/">
        /
      </button>
      <button id="multiply" value="x">
        x
      </button>
      <button id="seven" value="7">
        7
      </button>
      <button id="eight" value="8">
        8
      </button>
      <button id="nine" value="9">
        9
      </button>
      <button id="subtract" value="-">
        -
      </button>
      <button id="four" value="4">
        4
      </button>
      <button id="five" value="5">
        5
      </button>
      <button id="six" value="6">
        6
      </button>

      <button id="add" value="+">
        +
      </button>

      <button id="one" value="1" onClick={handleNumbers}>
        1
      </button>
      <button id="two" value="2">
        2
      </button>
      <button id="three" value="3">
        3
      </button>
      <button id="equals" value="=">
        =
      </button>
      <button id="zero" value="0" className="jumbo">
        0
      </button>

      <button id="decimal" value=".">
        .
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

CSS;

```
#root {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  background: #c2c2d6;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.calculator {
  border: 2px solid #47476b;
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

#history {
  font-family: digital;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#display {
  font-size: 29px;
  font-family: digital;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  height: 65px;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
  background: #664659;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  border: none;

  font-family: Share Tech Mono, monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #c28cac;
  color: black;
  outline: 0.05em solid grey;
  z-index: 3;
}

.jumbo {
  width: 160px;
}
#equals {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var setInput = event.target.value shouldn't be called like this.
setInput is a function, think of it as a setter for your value.

Syntax for calling setInput would be like this:

```
//here you get value from event target.
const newValue = event.target.value;
//here you can print it to check value.
//and this is how you set..
setInput(newValue);
```

Please check out the react official documentation for use state: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: the function didn't change anything. I still can't render the app

Comment: Well defenetly, it did fix one problem, you might have few more,
I see one here: 

const Output = () 

you should be accepting props in params of this component...

Comment: after fixing props problem, if you have another copy paste error in comment section.
Also don't update inital post, becaus people can't see problems and fixes for them...

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleNumbers` function is defined on the `Calculator` component, and you are trying to use it inside the `Buttons` component.
To fix, simply pass in the function as a prop to `Buttons`

```
function Calculator() {
  // code ........
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="calculator">
        <History />
        <Output currentValue={input} />
        <Buttons handleNumbers={handleNumbers}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const Buttons = (props) => {
  // destructure the props here
  const {handleNumbers} = props;
  //...... rest of the code
```